# onCompleted of Apollo's useLazyQuery does not get called when the execute function resolves

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am facing a problem with the following snippet:

```js
const [execute] = useLazyQuery(gql`
  query Example($id: String!) {
    node(id: $id) {
      ... on Train {
        id
        passengers(first: 1) {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)

useEffect(() => {
  execute({ onCompleted: () => console.log("Hello world") })
}, [])
```

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
}

type PassengerConnection {
  totalCount: Int!
}

type Train {
  id: ID!
  passengers(first: Int): PassengerConnection!
}

type Query {
  node(id: String!): Node
}
```

Observing the network tab tells me that the server does return a response.
The execute function indeed returns a promise and this promise resolves to that response.

But `onCompleted` is not called in any circumstances

###### Expect

`onCompleted` gets run

##### What I've been doing

```js
result.data &&
previousResult?.networkStatus !== result.networkStatus &&
result.networkStatus === NetworkStatus.ready
```

The above snippet is used by Apollo to evaluate if it will run `onCompleted`.
Using the debug tool, I've gotten to know that it will be called 3 times, the first time with `{ loading: true, networkStatus: 1 }`, the second time with `{ loading: false, networkStatus: 7 }` and the third time with `{ data: {...}, loading: false, networkStatus: 7 }` while theoretically it should've been called 2 times

Please be mindful that adding `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` does not help :(

I'd like to ask what might be the cause to this
Thank you